# How to avoid blink when resizing canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I wrote this javascript to increase canvas size by 1 pixel whenever the ball hit the border. However, the whole canvas will blink when the size is changed. Don't know what causes this problem. Is there any way to fix?

```
function testWalls() {
    var ball;
    var testBall;

    for (var i =0; i <balls.length; i++) {
        ball = balls[i];

        if (ball.nextX+ball.radius > theCanvas.width) {
            ball.velocityX = ball.velocityX*-1;
            ball.nextX = theCanvas.width - ball.radius;
            theCanvas.width++;
            drawScreen();


        } else if (ball.nextX-ball.radius < 0 ) {
            ball.velocityX = ball.velocityX*-1;
            ball.nextX =  ball.radius;

        } else if (ball.nextY+ball.radius > theCanvas.height ) {
            ball.velocityY = ball.velocityY*-1;
            ball.nextY = theCanvas.height - ball.radius;
            theCanvas.height++;
            drawScreen();

        } else if(ball.nextY-ball.radius < 0) {
            ball.velocityY = ball.velocityY*-1;
            ball.nextY =  ball.radius;
        }


    }

}
```

a demo can be found here
http://converteveryunit.com/pot/demo3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't looked at your code, but there are a few things you can do, but I will mention two.

One is to buffer your code, so you would draw to an off-screen canvas, then put that on, but, the more important thing is not to clear the entire image, then redraw.

Clear just what is changing, and redraw that, which should fix your problem.

For more ideas on what you can do you can look at 
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/canvas/performance/

Answer (score 0):

You can use buffering.

Here is a good tutorial for it:

http://www.slideshare.net/ernesto.jimenez/5-tips-for-your-html5-games

Answer (score 0):

Nice application! :)

I think you might get a better user experience by making the sliders change canvas `onMouseUp` instead of `onMouseMove`.

Also, I noticed that some balls are spawning one inside another, and so they are getting stuck toguether forever. You could check collision before spawning to avoid that.